# How do I compare two date values from different objects, format them, and test for equality?

Tags: javascript, datetime, for-loop, object

I have two arrays containing objects.  One looks like this:

```
const seatGeekEvents = [
      {
        datetime_local: "2020-09-15T20:00:00",
        venue: {
          name: "House of Blues - Boston",
        },
      },
    ]; ...
```

and the other like this:

```
 const hourlyForecast = [
      {
        clouds: 40,
        dt: 1600200000, 
        temp: 67.44,
      },
    ]; ...
```

I would like to make a function that looks through the objects in the arrays, finds out if the time values in the objects are the same, and if they are, returns the data from the objects that have matching times.  Later on, I will display the data using HTML.

The eventual goal here is to make an html table of event data with weather data for the time the event starts.  The objects are responses returned from fetch.

Here's the function I've come up with to look for matches:

```
const getDataToDisplay = (seatGeekEvents, hourlyForecast) => {
      const dataToDisplay = [];
      for (i = 0; i < seatGeekEvents.length; i++) {
        const matches = [];
        for (j = 0; j < hourlyForecast.length; j++) {
          if (
            formatEventTime(seatGeekEvents[i].datetime_local) ===
            formatWeatherTime(hourlyForecast[j].dt)
          ) {
            matches.push(seatGeekEvents[i], hourlyForecast[j]);
          }
        }
        return matches;
      }
      return dataToDisplay;
    };

    console.log(getDataToDisplay(seatGeekEvents, hourlyForecast));
```

The formatting functions I'm using for coverting dt and datetime_local look like this

```
 const formatEventTime = (startTimeUTC) => {
      const date = new Date(startTimeUTC);
      return date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
        weekday: "long",
      });
    };

    const formatWeatherTime = (forecastTimeStamp) => {
      const milliseconds = forecastTimeStamp * 1000;
      const dateObject = new Date(milliseconds);
      return dateObject.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit",
        weekday: "long",
      });
    };
```

I'd like to understand why my getDataToDisplay() is returning an empty array.  Is it just a time formatting issue?  Thanks

Comment: "2020-09-15T20:00:00" doesn't have an associated offset so would represent a different moment in time in each different place with a different offset. 1600200000 is probably a time value in seconds since 1970-01-01 (making it represent "2020-09-15T20:00:00.000Z") which is a unique moment in time. How do you wish to treat the first timestamp?

Comment: Do not use the built–in parser. "2020-09-15T20:00:00" should be treated as local, but Safari treats it as UTC.

Comment: Thanks @RobG.  How do I wish to treat the first timestamp?  Whether I start by dealing with the first timetamp or the second is arbitrary.  I think my main issue is that I just don't know how to compare Unix to UTC in vanilla js.  (I'm bound by vanilla in this case)

Comment: @RobG thanks for letting me know about the built-in parser for Safari.   Currently working with Chrome. Will make a note to deal with both browsers.

Comment: @RobG I looked more closely at the weather response.  My fetch is for the America/New York timezone, with `timezone_offset: -14400` if that's useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"1600200000" is probably a time value in seconds since 1970-01-01 which, if it was UTC, resolves to "2020-09-15T20:00:00.000Z".

An offset of -14400 is probably also seconds which resolves to -4:00. So it seems that "1600200000" a local time value for offset -14400, which matches the current offset in New York.

Given a timestamp of "2020-09-15T20:00:00" and offset of -14400, you should parse the string as UTC, then adjust it using the offset to get a Date that can then be compared to other Dates.

E.g.

```js
/** Parse timestamp as UTC and apply provided offset
 *  @param {string} timestamp - ISO 8601 format, no timezone
 *  @param {number} offset    - Offset from UTC in seconds
 *  @returns {Date} for timestamp and offset
 */
function parseISO(timestamp, offset) {
  // Get values from timestamp
  let [Y,M,D,H,m,s] = timestamp.split(/\D/);
  // Parse as if UTC
  let date = new Date(Date.UTC(Y, M-1, D, H, m, s));
  // Apply offset to adjust to actual UTC
  date.setUTCSeconds(date.getUTCSeconds() - offset);
  return date;  
}

let timestamp = '2020-09-15T20:00:00';
let offset = -14400;
let date = parseISO(timestamp, offset);

console.log('New York: ' + date.toLocaleString('default', {timeZone:'America/New_York'}));
console.log('UTC     : ' + date.toISOString());
```

Note that if you want to compare events that are on the same day, you may need to work out how to deal with different time zones and what "same day" means.

Comment: I've tried applying your function but I'm still having some trouble.  How would you apply your function `parseISO` to test for equality with the unix timestamp I'm comparing it to?  I assume I will need another function to parse the unix timestamps from `hourlyForecast`?

Comment: and all - let me know if I should clarify or condense the question; happy to re-ask in a cleaner way

Comment: @elderlyman—given the UNIX timestamp is seconds, then `new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000)` gives you an equivalent ECMAScript Date. Compare away.

Comment: In the end I think this was a poorly asked question on my part.  I tried to set up concise test data from an excess of real data, and things got messy.  But I learned a lot from researching your answer! Thanks